# send multiple datatable from controller and iterate those in view asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In my ASP.Net MVC 4, I would like to send multiple datatable from a controller to a view. Then those datatables are to be iterated in that view. How can i do it? I'm a new comer to mvc world.

Thank you in anticipation.

Update- I know how to send a single datatable to a view and iterate. But i need to know the technique when multiple tables are involved.

Update- my view is a partial view.

Comment: In general a strongly-typed model is preferred over a `DataTable`.  But technically a `DataTable` is an object like any other, so there's no reason you can't use it as a model.  You'd just reference its properties like any other model from any MVC tutorial.  Have you made any attempt?  Or are you at the pre-tutorial stage and should really be looking for some MVC walk-throughs?

Comment: Can you show us how you send your DataTable to View, and can you show us some code of View and Controller. Have you tried to return List<DataTable> to View and iterate through it?

Comment: @freshbm, ore vodai, ami parle ki ar tore jigaitam!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to create a class that will be acting as your ViewModel (a class serving your view and providing the view with neede data), then this class may be consists of N properties  as you need.

then all you need inside your controller is to create a new object of this class, fill in your class properties (say your desired 4 datatables) and send this class object to your view so you will be able to iterate over your tables with ease.

**Example:**

```
public class MyDataViewModel()
{

  public DataTable FirstTable {get; set;}
  public DataTable SecondTable {get; set;}
  public DataTable ThirdTable {get; set;}
  public DataTable ForthTable {get; set;}
}
```

inside your controller, create a new object and fill the data inside your properties

```
var myDataObject = new MyDataViewModel();
myDataObject.FirstTable = // your First Table  data ;
myDataObject.SecondTable = // your Second Table data ;
myDataObject.ThirdTable = // your Third Table  data ;
myDataObject.ForthTable = // your Forth Table  data ;

return view(myDataObject);
```

**Note:** your final representation will depend on your situation, my guess is that you don't need datatables, and better to create `List<YOUR_OBJECT>` which will hold the data to your view

**Update:** to create `List<YOUR_OBJECT>` items instead of your Datatables, you will modify the ViewModel class properties to be `List<YOUR_OBJECT>` instead of DataTables, very simple I guess :).

Comment: downvoted. this defeats the purpose of the whole MVC infrastructure. Why give a bloated POCO in a class and passing it to the view? Remember - clear separation is the key here. you need to create a model which has the properties you wish to represent the data to the view (either for edit or display mode). Also having such a model as I have described is less load in all aspects (memory and performance) than a bloated DataTable object embedded in a class.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas: I'm addressing his specific problem, and hinting for a better approach, I can understand your point here, but he said he need to know the technique of sending multiple items in one patch, mine was an example, not a pattern to follow.

Comment: @Elsayed - no problem my friend.

Comment: @Mohammed ElSayed, thanks for your help. You are recommending to use models. In that case, how can i send multiple List<T> models to the view and iterate? P

Answer (score 1):

It is better practice, and recommended, to use a model to represent the data. This is the point on MVC. Sure, you could use a datatable but why?

Remember, datatable only contains single table data. you either have a DataSet, which contains multiple tables or just a general collection of datatables.

if you are using a dataset....

Create your model with properties, then iterate through the datatables in the dataset, for each table, for each row and add the model you are creating for the current row/table in a collection. Finally, pass that collection back to the View.

to iterate through the tables in a dataset...

```
DataSet ds = this.GetDataSet();
            foreach (DataTable currentTable in ds.Tables)
            {
                foreach (DataRow currentRow in currentTable.Rows)
                {
                    // looping through each row within this datatable
// at this point, you need to then map the current row data to the Model. I'll let you deal with this
                }
            }
```

it would be good if you can show some code you are currently using.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you create a view in MVC, you bind a model/ViewModel to that view. Taking into consideration your requirement, you need to first create viewModels/models of the corresponding datatables, bind your data from the datatable into Lists of corresponding models/ViewModels and then pass them into the view. For iterating multiple datatables, you need to use partial views of diff. models. )